# How to customize Devise to store more informations in the session?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, session, devise

It seems that when Devise logs a user in, only the user id is stored in the session.
This means that whenever calling `current_user` will result in a SQL query (something like `User.find(:id)`) to create the User object, which in many cases is unnecessary load.
For example, we may want to display the user's name in the top-right header, which is in the layout file and gets rendered in every response. For that we may just write `current_user.name`, which causes a SQL query to the users table.

I really want to store some basic informations(such as the name and email) of the current user in the session, to avoid that extra SQL query.

What is the right solution to this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get over it already. That SQL query is effectively free. If you are really seeing performance issues from `User.find(id)`, then your app/database/server are completely screwed.

Furthermore, by storing more data in the session, you open up the possibility of displaying data that is no longer current. Do you allow the user to edit their info - if so, what happens when they edit their name? It is hassle that has no real payoff.

Comment: why do you say "That SQL query is effectively free"? I think this is indeed an extra query that should be avoided. and, when the user updates his name, we only need to update the session.

Comment: That query uses the primary key to find a record, so the database is going to return that record extremely fast. Next, ActiveRecord will instantiate the record object, but a single AR record is, again, very quick to build. Rule #1: profile before and after optimizing. This sounds to me like thoughtless premature optimization. If adding this user retrieval causes a significant change to your page build time then either a) your app isn't doing anything else with the database or b) your database table/index is screwed up and needs to be fixed or re-tuned.