# How to using current_user in devise without hitting database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have the same question with  [How to customize Devise to store more informations in the session?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6868160/how-to-customize-devise-to-store-more-informations-in-the-session)

When I use `current_user` and `user_signed_in?` devise helper, both will cause a SQL query to hitting database. Is there a better way to retrieve these information in session without hitting database ?

Is it necessary to assign session by myself after user login phase ?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want it to hit the database, then don't use one to store your sessions. Instead, store the sessions in memory. You've got a few options for this such as memcached using the [Dalli gem](https://github.com/mperham/dalli) or redis using the [redis-store gem](https://github.com/jodosha/redis-store). These are not the only gem options, but they are popular ones. I encourage you to explore what else is out there to see what would be a good fit for you.

Comment: Thanks. Just want to decrease loading of database.

Comment: It needs to locate the session from somewhere, so if you want to decrease loading on the database, you need to move it to somewhere else.

Comment: Eventhough he would use Redis or Memcached for storing sessions; how could he retrieve data of a `User` object which is stored in a `users` table of the RDBMS? If you have an answer for this; please also take a look at my question :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23168428/should-each-request-cost-2-database-hits-when-using-devisecancanrolify

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes you require only the `:id` of the user, in such a case you can write the following method in application controller which uses session

```
def current_user_id
  session[:user_id] = session[:user_id] || current_user.id
end
```

Comment: Ruby way: session[:user_id] ||= current_user.id