# Should each request cost 2 database hits when using Devise+CanCan+Rolify?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, session-cookies, cancan, rolify

As much as I can understand, regardless of chosen session store, a Rails app sends one database query for Devise and one database query for Rolify.

Here is my related code:

```
<% if !user_signed_in? %>
 ..login  buttons...
<% else %>
<% unless current_user.has_role? :pro %>
 <%= link_to "Upgrade!", '#' %> |
<% end %>
  <%= link_to current_user.full_name, edit_user_registration_path %> |<%= link_to "Çıkış", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %>
<% end %>
```

Those codes causes these SQL queries as I can see from my development logs:

```
12:30:22 web.1  |   User Load (2.6ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 352 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
12:30:22 web.1  |    (2.7ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "roles" INNER JOIN "users_roles" ON "roles"."id" = "users_roles"."role_id" WHERE "users_roles"."user_id" = $1 AND (((roles.name = 'pro') AND (roles.resource_type IS NULL) AND (roles.resource_id IS NULL)))  [["user_id", 352]]
```

The thing I wonder is, are all of these queries necessary? Isn't there a better way to do this?

If I'm not mistaken, `user_signed_in?` helper method always sends a call to database.

Why it doesn't just check out if `session` object exists? After the user logs in, desired attributes of `User` object could be stored in `session` and would be no need to hit database each time a page requested? All cookies are safe with Rails 4, so what is the problem?

Probably I'm missing something.

Can someone make this clear, please?

Thank you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1095714/storing-objects-in-a-session-in-rails and http://railscasts.com/episodes/13-dangers-of-model-in-session do a pretty good job explaining why this is a bad idea.

Comment: thanks for answer. why don't you write it as an answer and I can accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

josevalim's answer is as [follows](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/2989):

> "*If I'm not mistaken, user_signed_in? helper method always sends a
>   call to database.*"
>
> It sends a call and then caches it. We need to load the session and
>   try to load the user because the user could have been removed from the
>   database. Or the user time to access the application may have expired
>   and so on.